# nodejs python-shell error on raspberry pi

Tags: python, node.js, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I'm working on nodejs on raspberry pi, base on the python's basic code suppose to run working on pi:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(7, True)
```

But when I tried on [python shell package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) to run the python script from the above. It throws an error:

**Error: process exited with code 2
    at ChildProcess. (/home/pi/Desktop/Social_Feed/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:82:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1067:12)**

The Javascript to run the Python-shell is:

```
 var PythonShell = require('..');
PythonShell.run('anythingcodes.py', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
      console.log('finished');
  });
```

Does anyone tested using python-shell to run any python script on the raspberry pi's GPIO ?

Comment: Could you please add the JavaScript code used to call that Python module‽ Accessing GPIO might need root privileges — are you running this as normal user?

Comment: Hi BlackJack, the javascript is at the above that I've just edited my post. And by the way where do I check if im running my raspberry pi as normal user or administrator?